# Сегменты данных, кода и кучи при страничной организации памяти

Tags: виртуальная-память

возьмем Windows в качестве примера. Я знаю, что эта ОС использует страничную организацию памяти. Но к программам работающим под эту ОС все так-же применимы понятия сегмент данных, сегмент кода, сегмент кучи и т. д., так ли это? Правильно ли я понимаю, что это не те сегменты, [которые были на х86 машинах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)? Как тогда происходит адресация по ним?

Comment: Вообще это все те же сегменты что по ссылке. Кроме случая работы процессора в long mode https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64. В long mode сегменты остаются на усмотрение ОС, например она запрещает выполнение кода на уровне страниц (бит XD таблицы страниц), распределенных под сегменты данных и стека.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. Но если мы возьмём именно Windows? В ней же не используется сегментация даже если процессор работает в legacy mode, не так ли? Что тогда происходит с этими сегментами?

Comment: В legacy в сегментные регистры надо загрузить значения, причем разные, потому что они явно говорят что это за сегмент. И да, ОС может и linux точно и возможно и windows грузят туда одни и те же значения для всех процессов. остальное разруливается страничным преобразованияем, собственным для каждого процесса. И да, в выполнимых файлах exe всегда есть разделение на сегменты. И это используется для того что бы дать этим участкам памяти разные привилегии. И ОС надо перенести эти привилегии на страничный уровень, даже если нет защиты со стороны сегментов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В ней же не используется сегментация даже если процессор работает в legacy mode, не так ли? Что тогда происходит с этими сегментами?

ОС здесь не имеет значения, а алгоритм поддерживается самим процессором на аппаратном уровне, при переходе из реального в защищённый режим. При этом (как правило) на сегментную накладывается страничная организация.

Процессор имеет 6 сегментных регистра: CS\DS\SS\ES\FS\GS (кода, данных, стека, расширенный, и два дополнительных). Таким образом сегмента кучи не бывает.

Размер этих регистров по 10-байт, и каждый из них хранит две составляющие: 2-байтный видимый **"селектор"**, и 8-байтный скрытый **"дескриптор"**. В селекторе имеется 2-битное поле **"RPL"** (Request Privelege Level, уровень привилегии запроса), в котором лежит номер кольца защиты 0-3. Если код выполняется в режиме ядра, то RPL=0, если под юзером, то RPL=3.

Дескриптор-же описывает уже сам сегмент памяти. Из основных полей дескриптора можно выделить "Базу" (всегда нуль), "Лимит" (всегда макс 4 ГБ), разные атрибуты, и 4-битное поле "Type". Именно в этом поле хранится тип сегмента, который может быть кодовым (доступным для исполнения), или данных. Сегмент стека - это такой-же сегмент данных, только с взведённым битом **"Expand-Down"** (обратное расширение). В доках Интела том(3) есть скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот расшифровка 4-битного поля "Type" (красным выделены биты сегмента-стека):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В системе имеется таблица GDT (Global Descriptor Table), где хранятся дескрипторы всех-шести сегментов. Инструкция ассемблера `SGDT` читает эту таблицу (Store), а `LGDT` записывает в неё новые значения (Load).

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. А поддержка сегментного алгоритма имеется только у процессоров intel, или у всех процессоров?

Comment: Так-же насчёт кучи, как тогда ее адресуют если она не является сегментом? Получается, что куча это часть какого другого сегмента или как?

Comment: `>>  или у всех процессоров?` - у всех, как Intel, так и AMD. А на счёт кучи я уже говорил, что на сегментную модель в РМ накладывается страничная. Для каждого процесса система создаёт свой каталог вирт.страниц "PageDirectory", на который указывает регистр CR3. В каталоге имеется таблица страниц, а в ней записи PageTableEntry (PTE). Каждая такая запись размером 32-бит и описывает одну страницу вирт.памяти, Среди этих битов есть бит атрибута R/W. Таким образом куча - это сегмент данных, пространство которого делится на 4Кб вирт.страницы с нужными атрибутами.

Comment: вот небольшой ликбез на эту тему: https://www.cyberforum.ru/low-level/thread2107770.html#post11667546

Comment: Кстати в РТЕ нет бита Execute, поэтому на 32-бит системах если страница доступна на запись, то она автоматом становится доступной и на исполнение. Поэтому на х64 увеличили размер записей РТЕ до 64-бит, а самый старший бит(63) выделили под `XD` (eXecute Disable), чтобы предотвратить исполнение данных.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить. Читаю статью: `Отличительной особенность плоской модели памяти является то, что сегменты и страницы могут начинаться с любого адреса`, но вот [определение плоской модели памяти](https://hrwiki.ru/wiki/Flat_memory_model)  - `Модель плоской памяти или ... без необходимости прибегать к каким-либо видам схемы сегментации памяти или подкачки.` Каким образом при плоской модели памяти могут быть сегменты и страницы?